# Framework design - why does .net provide ObfuscateAssemblyAttribute when it does not implement obfuscation?

Tags: .net, obfuscation, mscorlib

I was browsing some assemblies in `ILSpy`, and came across `System.Reflection.ObfuscateAssemblyAttribute` in `mscorlib`.

I don't understand why this attribute is included in the .net framework. I would understand if it were provided by a vendor of obfuscation tools (like `DotFuscator`), but then it would be in a custom supplied assembly, and not in `System`.

I would expect attributes to configure obfuscation to differ per vendor, as the would probalby support diffrent kinds of obfusation.

The .Net framework does not support obfuscation tooling (for so far is i know).

Why is this attribute part of the .Net framework? (in `mscorlib` no less!)

Comment: There is an attempt at explaining its use [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.obfuscateassemblyattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

> I would understand if it were provided by a vendor of obfuscation tools (like DotFuscator), but then it would be in a custom supplied assembly, and not in System.

If it was done this way, the code would have a hard dependency on the obfuscation tool... With this attribute defined in the .NET Framework itself, the code can be completely ignorant of which obfuscation tool (if any) will be used.

(note: this is just my guess, so it might not be the real reason at all...)